# Specify a different name for a specific value to be used in the search bar of a datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I have a basic shiny app below with a datatable. Ι was wondering if it is possible to search in the search bar of the datatable for the species "setosa" but with another name which has to be set earlier. For example typing "sts" will give all the "setosa" species.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE)
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: I don't see a good way to do it from the R API, but you could include a JS code snippet to access the DOM element associated with your table and run this function on it: https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()

Comment: if you find an answer do not hesitate to pass it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define an abbreviation column and hide it (searching still works):

```
iris$Abbreviation <- "sts"
iris$Abbreviation[iris$Species == "versicolor"] <- "vrs"
iris$Abbreviation[iris$Species == "virginica"] <- "vrg"

hideCols <- which(names(iris) %in% c("Abbreviation"))

library(shiny)
library(DT)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl')),
  server = function(input, output) {
    output$tbl = renderDT(
      iris, options = list(lengthChange = FALSE, columnDefs = list(list(visible=FALSE, targets=hideCols)))
    )
  }
)
```